# Getting started with Orchard on Azure

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I'm trying to set up an Orchard site to deploy to Azure, but have fallen at the first hurdle. I've downloaded the source code and opened Orchard.Azure.sln, but when I run it I get the error:

Access to the path 'C:\APPG\src\Orchard.Azure\Orchard.Azure.Web\App_Data\Dependencies' is denied.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a complete noob with Azure, so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't actually Azure related, but you need to ensure that the identity that your website is running under has write access to the App_Data folder. Either give the IIS user access, or change the application pool identity in IIS to Network Service. When Orchard starts for the first time, it writes a whole bunch of stuff to folders below App_Data.

Bear this in mind if you need to install fresh at any time. Simply deleting the contents of that folder and creating a new, blank database (or using the compact option) will start afresh.